# How do I write a shopping cart code written in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

```js
class ShoppingCart {

 function() {
  this.total = 0;
  this.items = {};
 }

 addItem(itemName, quantity, price) {
  this.total += price;
  this.items["itemName"] = quantity; 
 }

 removeItem(itemName, quantity, price) {
  if (quantity > this.items["itemName"]) {
   delete this.items["itemName"];
  }
  else {
   delete this.items["itemName"](this.items["itemName"] - quantity);
  }
  this.total -= price;
 }

 checkout(cashPaid) {
  if (cashPaid > this.total) {
   var balance = cashPaid - this.total;
   return "Your balance is " + balance;
  }
  else if (cashPaid < this.total) {
   return "Cash paid is not enough";
  }
  else {
   return "Thanks for shopping with us, Have a lovely day";
  }
 }

};

class Shop extends ShoppingCart {

 function() {
  this.quantity = 100;
 }

 removeItem() {
  this.items["itemName"]--; //decrements quantity of items by 1
 }

};
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'itemName' of undefined

I am running it with node v6.6.0 and I've tried running it on chrome console too, it isn't working. The truth is that I haven't gotten the hang of OOP in Javascript yet, please help me out. Thanks

Comment: shouldn't `function() {` be `constructor() {`

Comment: you'll also need `super()` before `this.quantity = 100;` in class Shop

Comment: check this out... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: checked it out, thanks for your help @Jalil, and I've checked the documentation too, but the truth is that I've not gotten a full hang of how OOP is written in JS

Comment: thank you @JaromandaX, I've corrected that but that hasn't solved the error yet

Comment: well ... it should've. Perhaps you did it wrong - update the code in the question

Comment: I have updated the code, this is the error I get now    /home/codewarrior/mocha:20
   delete this.items["itemName"](this.items["itemName"] - quantity);
                               ^

TypeError: this.items.itemName is not a function
    at ShoppingCart.removeItem

Comment: @D-Beloved you did not pay attention to the first two comments and understand better the classes docs. In classes docs, they don't user function(){} for initializing values like in your code that is why you need to use constructor(){} instead. So when you call this.items in your methods they are not available.